Manga in which the father leaves or sacrifices his daughter so that his son could have powers
I am looking for a manga in which the father leaves or sacrifices his daughter so that his son could have powers but the daughter locked inside the room get the powers instead many hands appear inside that room and saved that girl.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Is this The Monstrous Duke's Adopted Daughter...?

The Speràdo family line possesses a secret: shadow magic. But it’s been 100 years since someone last wielded it. When Marquis Speràdo tries to sacrifice Leslie for her favored sister Ellie, little does he know that this awakens the power of darkness in her instead. To escape her family’s greed and abuse, Leslie’s out to make a deal with the Monstrous Duke: adopt her, and her powers will be at the duke’s disposal. Will Leslie escape her parents’ cruel grip, or succumb to their evil exploits?

Leslie Speràdo is the second and youngest daughter of the noble Speràdo family. They bore her for the express purpose of sacrificing her, so that her elder sister, Ellie, would gain shadow powers.
Her father eventually tries to sacrifice her by throwing her into a burning room, but several spectral hands appear in the room and save her by pushing her out of a window.

 

Leslie later discovers that the Sperado family have made a practice of sacrificing its younger children like this for the last thousand years, and that the spirits who saved her were those of previously sacrificed children.
You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.
